# Adobe Illustrator SVG to WPF xaml weird error Makes PNG

Tags: c#, wpf, svg

I designed this nice user interface in Adobe Illustrator.  Now I am trying to convert it over to WPF   Xaml.

Normally I use inkscape to  blend,  but that has not been working for this   illustration.   So I decide to use  Microsoft Express designer 4.

So it is working,  however;  it is giving me a PNG.

And I am very confused about that.  Also it seems to make my system run slower I'm assuming because there's a PNG involved.

below, is a link to all the files, I am talking about:

[enter link description here][1]

How do I Fix this ?
Ps
This particular component is one of the ones that's causing problems and that is making these PNGs.

It is not the only one.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FhaKPc75BnoACBQu1kUTNHqrU0OQorVy?usp=sharing

Comment: can anyone  help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your original SVG contains bitmap images.  So that means your AI and XAML versions will also.

If you don't want your XAML to use bitmaps, then make sure your SVG and AI files don't either.

Also be aware that some effects that you can apply with Illustrator may not be supported in XAML. In those situations what Illustrator may do is generate a bitmap version of that object in order to preserve the look of the effect.